# MATLAB efficient histogram look up

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, histogram

I have a large 3-dimensional matrix (on the order of 1000x1000x100) containing values that correspond to a bins in normalized high-resolution histograms. There is one histogram for every index in the 3rd matrix dimension (e.g. 100 histograms for the example dimensions).

What is the fastest way to check the find the probability (i.e. the value associated with a bin in a normalized histogram) of the value at the 2D indices?

The code I have now is exorbitantly slow:

```
probs = zeros(rows, cols, dims);
for k = 1 : dims
    tmp = data(:,:,k);
    [h, centers] = hist(tmp, 1000);
    h = h / sum(h); % Normalize the histogram
    for r = 1 : rows
        for c = 1 : cols
            % Identify bin center closest to value
            [~, idx] = min(abs(centers - data(r, c, k)));
            probs(r,c,k) = h(idx);
        end
    end
end
```

For loops are generally (although not always) less efficient than vectorized code, and nest for loops are usually even worse. How can I go about doing this with fewer loops but also without running out of memory? I tried some repmat calls to vectorize the whole process, but crashed my MATLAB session with 1000x1000x1000x100 matrices.

NOTE: I only have MATLAB 2014a, so while solutions using the new [`histogram()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function are welcome, I'm still stuck with [`hist()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html).

Here's a small-scale demo example that should run in a replicable way:

```
rng(2); % Seed the RNG for repeatability
rows = 3;
cols = 3;
dims = 2;
data = repmat(1:3,3,1,2);
probs = zeros(rows, cols, dims);
for k = 1 : dims
    tmp = normrnd(0,1,1000,1);
    [h, centers] = hist(tmp);
    h = h / sum(h); % Normalize the histogram
    for r = 1 : rows
        for c = 1 : cols
            % Identify bin center closest to value
            [~, idx] = min(abs(centers - data(r, c, k)));
            probs(r,c,k) = h(idx);
        end
    end
end
```

When I ran the above code, I got the following output (which is logical as the histogram is a normal Gaussian):

```
probs(:,:,1) =

0.1370    0.0570    0.0030
0.1370    0.0570    0.0030
0.1370    0.0570    0.0030


probs(:,:,2) =

0.1330    0.0450    0.0050
0.1330    0.0450    0.0050
0.1330    0.0450    0.0050
```

NOTE: I found an efficient solution to this as posted in the answer below.

Comment: Can you give a small example with desired inputs and output? Say with a 3x3x2 array

Comment: @LuisMendo I added a copy/paste example that should demo exactly what I'm looking for. Remember, speed at these small dimensions is irrelevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEST SOLUTION:

Without using the new [`histogram()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function (i.e. all versions before R2014b), the best way to do this is to take advantage of both the [`hist()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function and the [`histc()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) function in tandem.

There are two cases to consider as well:

1. Binning data and then looking up the same data in the histogram
2. Looking up bins in a histogram formed from different data

The first case is the simpler one. A nice feature of `histc()` is that it returns both the histogram and the indices of the histogram into which the data was binned. At this point, we should be done. Alas! Sadly we are not. Because the code behind `histc()` and `hist()` bins the data differently, we end up with two different histograms depending on which we use. The reason appears to be that `histc()` chooses bins based on a **strictly greater-than** criteria, while `hist()` chooses bins using **greater-than-or-equal-to**. As a result, the equivalent function call:

```
% Using histc
binEdges = linspace(min(tmp),max(tmp),numBins+1);
[h1, indices] = histc(data, binEdges);

% Using hist
[h2, indices] = hist(data, numBins);
```

leads to different histograms: `length(h1) - length(h2) = 1`.

So to handle this we can just add the value in the last bin of `h1` to the value in the second-to-last bin of `h1`, lop off that last bin, and adjust the indices accordingly:

```
% Account for "strictly greater than" bug that results in an extra bin

h1(:, numBins) = h1(:, numBins) + h1(:, end); % Combine last two bins
indices(indices == numBins + 1) = numBins; % Adjust indices to point to right spot
h1 = h1(:, 1:end-1); % Lop off the extra bin
```

Now you are left with an `h1` that matches `h2` and and `indices` vector corresponding to where your data went in `h1`. Thus, you can look up the probability information by efficient indexing instead of loops.

Runnable sample code:

```
rng(2); % Seed the RNG for repeatability

% Generate some data
numBins = 6;
data = repmat(rand(1,5), 3, 1, 2);
[rows, cols, dims] = size(data);
N = rows*cols;

% Bin all data into a histogram, keeping track of which bin each data point
% gets mapped to
h = zeros(dims, numBins + 1);
indices = zeros(dims, N);
for k = 1 : dims
    tmp = data(:,:,k);
    tmp = tmp(:)';
    binEdges = linspace(min(tmp),max(tmp),numBins+1);
    [h(k,:), indices(k,:)] = histc(tmp, binEdges);
end

% Account for "strictly greater than" bug that results in an extra bin
h(:, numBins) = h(:, numBins) + h(:, end); % Add count in last bin to the second-to-last bin
indices(indices == numBins + 1) = numBins; % Adjust indices accordingly
h = h(:,1:end-1); % Lop off the extra bin
h = h ./ repmat(sum(h,2), 1, numBins); % Normalize all histograms

% Now we can efficiently look up probabilities by indexing instead of
% looping
for k = 1 : dims
    probs(:, :, k) = reshape(h(sub2ind(size(h), repmat(k, 1, size(indices, 2)), indices(k,:))), rows, cols);
end
probs
```

In the second case, look-ups are tougher because you don't have the luxury of tracking bin-indices during histogram creation. However, we can work around this by building a second histogram with identical bins to the first, and tracking the indices during the binning process.

For this approach, you first compute an initial histogram using `hist()` on some histogram training data. All you need to store are the minimum and maximum values of that training data. With this information, we can generate the same histogram using [`linspace()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) and `histc()`, adjusting for the extra-bin "bug" that `histc()` gives.

The key here is to handle outlier data. That is, the data from your new data set that falls outside the pre-computed histogram. As that should be assigned a frequency/probability of 0, we just add an extra bin to the pre-computed histogram with a value of 0, and we direct any unbinned new data to map to that index.

Here is some commented, runnable code for this second method:

```
% PRE-COMPUTE A HISTOGRAM
rng(2); % Seed the RNG for repeatability

% Build some data
numBins = 6;
old_data = repmat(rand(1,5), 3, 1, 2);
[rows, cols, dims] = size(old_data);

% Store min and max of each histogram for reconstruction process
min_val = min(old_data, [], 2);
max_val = max(old_data, [], 2);

% Just use hist() function while specifying number of bins this time
% No need to track indices because we are going to be using this histogram
% as a reference for looking up a different set of data
h = zeros(dims, numBins);
for k = 1 : dims
    tmp = old_data(:,:,k);
    tmp = tmp(:)';
    h(k,:) = hist(tmp, numBins);
end
h = h ./ repmat(sum(h, 2), 1, numBins); % Normalize histograms
h(:, end + 1) = 0; % Map to here any data to that falls outside the pre-computed histogram

% NEW DATA
rng(3); % Seed RNG again for repeatability

% Generate some new data
new_data = repmat(rand(1,4), 4, 1, 2); % NOTE: Doesn't have to be same size
[rows, cols, dims] = size(new_data);
N = rows*cols;


% Bin new data with histc() using boundaries from pre-computed histogram
h_new = zeros(dims, numBins + 1);
indices_new = zeros(dims, N);
for k = 1 : dims
    tmp = new_data(:,:,k);
    tmp = tmp(:)';

    % Determine bins for new histogram with the same boundaries as
    % pre-computed one. This ensures that our resulting histograms are
    % identical, except for the "greater-than" bug which is accounted for
    % below.
    binEdges = linspace(min_val(k), max_val(k), numBins+1);
    [h_new(k,:), indices_new(k,:)] = histc(tmp, binEdges);
end

% Adjust for the "greater-than" bug
% When adjusting this histogram, we are directing outliers that don't
% fit into the pre-computed histogram to look up probabilities from that 
% extra bin we added to the pre-computed histogram.
h_new(:, numBins) = h_new(:, numBins) + h_new(:, end); % Add count in last bin to the second-to-last bin
indices_new(indices_new == numBins + 1) = numBins; % Adjust indices accordingly
indices_new(indices_new == 0) = numBins + 1; % Direct any unbinned data to the 0-probability last bin
h_new = h_new ./ repmat(sum(h_new,2), 1, numBins + 1); % Normalize all histograms

% Now we should have all of the new data binned into a histogram
% that matches the pre-computed one. The catch is, we now have the indices
% of the bins the new data was matched to. Thus, we can now use the same
% efficient indexing-based look-up strategy as before to get probabilities
% from the pre-computed histogram.
for k = 1 : dims
    probs(:, :, k) = reshape(h(sub2ind(size(h), repmat(k, 1, size(indices_new, 2)), indices_new(k,:))), rows, cols);
end
probs
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a matrix `centersAll` (with `dims` rows) containing the histogram centers for each third-dimension index, and a similar matrix `hAll` (with `dims` rows) containing the histogram values.

Reshape `centersAll` into the third and fourth dimensions, use `bsxfun` to compute differences, minimize along the fourth dimension, and use that to index `hAll`:

```
[~, idx] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, data, reshape(centersAll,1,1,dims,[]))), [], 4);
hAllt = hAll.'; %'
probs2 = hAllt(bsxfun(@plus, idx, reshape(0:dims-1, 1,1,[])*size(hAll,2)));
```

Check:

```
%// Data
clear all
rng(2); % Seed the RNG for repeatability
rows = 3;
cols = 3;
dims = 2;
data = repmat(1:3,3,1,2);
for k = 1 : dims
    tmp = normrnd(0,1,1000,1);
    [h, centers] = hist(tmp);
    h = h / sum(h); % Normalize the histogram                   
    centersAll(k,:) = centers;
    hAll(k,:) = h;
end

%// With loops
probs = zeros(rows, cols, dims);
for k = 1 : dims
    for r = 1 : rows
        for c = 1 : cols
            % Identify bin center closest to value
            centers = centersAll(k,:);
            h = hAll(k,:);
            [~, idx] = min(abs(centers - data(r, c, k)));
            probs(r,c,k) = h(idx);
        end
    end
end

%// Without loops
[~, idx] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, data, reshape(centersAll,1,1,dims,[]))), [], 4);
hAllt = hAll.'; %'
probs2 = hAllt(bsxfun(@plus, idx, reshape(0:dims-1, 1,1,[])*size(hAll,2)));

%// Check
probs==probs2
```

gives

```
ans(:,:,1) =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
```